How to stop undesired edit from being suggested on and on?
There is a question on main site where one user is suggesting undesirable edit (for the 3rd time now):

I has been approved (why?) first time and then rolled back by myself
Rejected second time
Is back in "Suggested edits" queue

Such edit has several reasons to be rejected:

No improvement
Multiple pictures instead of one that is already easy to understand
Original picture has video name, if anyone needs to find the source
Edit could/should be posted as answer instead, since it contains details needed for an answer (part numbers)

How can we stop this kind of edits to be suggested on and on?

For this particular case, the edits don't seem to make any significant improvements on the question.
It is strange that the new images added in the revision actually include part numbers for most of the parts, so this seems more like an attempt to answer the question.
The edit can be rejected as 'No improvement', '
Clearly conflicts with author's intent' and possibly 'Attempt to reply' but I will reject the edit.
Either way I have rejected the edit and blocked the user from suggesting edits for 24 hours. The user may be contacted and blocked for a longer duration if necessary.

How can we stop this kind of edits to be suggested on and on?

This doesn't seem to be a common issue so on a case-by-case basis I would suggest:

Reject unwarranted edits. (Using the last reject reason allows you to leave a comment)
For repeated edits, flag the post as being 'in need of moderator intervention' and leave a descriptive comment.


Also I noticed the [technic] tag has been replaced with [clone-brands] ?

[clone-brands] has been added by myself since BuWizz is present on a picture and has been asked to identify. There were multiple edits and one of them might have dropped the [technic] tag.
